# What does "sh -c" do?

Tags: node.js, docker, unix, sh, google-cloud-run

I am trying to work with nginx in my express app and I'm following the tutorial here

https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/deploy-react-nginx-cloud-run

then at the end I saw this command

```
CMD sh -c "envsubst '\$PORT' < /etc/nginx/conf.d/configfile.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
```

Please what does the above command do?

Most specifically what does `"envsubst '\$PORT' < /etc/nginx/conf.d/configfile.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"` do?

Also, how do I run another command after that command above, because it seems I can't have multiple `CMD` statements. I need to run the below after that last command

`CMD["node","server.js"]`

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/1/sh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of `sh -c` here is already precisely to run multiple commands in one statement. The string after `-c` can contain an arbitrary number of commands, separated by command separators. Just add more, as many as you like.

`CMD sh -c "envsubst '\$PORT' < /etc/nginx/conf.d/configfile.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && nginx -g 'daemon off;' && node server.js"`

At some point, as the command line grows more complex, it makes more senso to put the commands in a file, `COPY` it into the container, and then simply put that file as your `CMD`. You can also create it within your `Dockerfile`;

```
RUN printf '%s\n' >cmd.sh \
    "envsubst '\$PORT' < /etc/nginx/conf.d/configfile.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf &&" \
    "nginx -g 'daemon off;' &&" \
    "node server.js"
# ...
CMD ["sh", "cmd.sh"]
```

As for what these commands do,

```
envsubst '\$PORT' < /etc/nginx/conf.d/configfile.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

generates `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` from the template file `/etc/nginx/conf.d/configfile.temp` by running the `envsubst` command; see its [manual page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/envsubst.1.html) for details. (The backslash before the dollar sign in `$PORT` isn't really part of the command; it's required because the enclosing string is interpreted by Docker, which has its own variable substitution mechanism, which would replace the value at build time if the dollar sign wasn't escaped; we don't want that here.)

```
&&
```

is a command separator which says to only proceed if the previous command succeeded. In other words, `a && b` runs `a`, and `b` if `a` didn't fail. (Success or failure is determined by examining the exit code from `a`,  which is also momentarily available in the shell variable `$?` until you run another external command.)

```
nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

runs `nginx` with the string as the argument to the `-g` option. Again, refer to the [man page](https://manpages.org/nginx) for details.

Answer (score 1):

`sh -c` just means you are giving your shell (sh) a commande to execute as parameter.
In your case, it would be 'like' typing in a terminal on the docker instance  `envsubst '\$PORT' < /etc/nginx/conf.d/configfile.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && nginx -g 'daemon off;'`
`
This line set the nginx config of your container.

to run node **from** your docker instance, use

```
RUN node server.js
```

I recommand this quick read on Docker run and cmd command : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-run-vs-cmd-vs-entrypoint-docker-commands/

Answer (score 1):

Specific to this setup, three answers:

**There's never a reason to use `CMD sh -c '...'`.**  [@tripleee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74415891) describes when you need `sh -c` in general.  The Dockerfile [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) directive has two forms, though, and if you use its [shell form](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell-form-entrypoint-example) (the command is not a JSON array) then Docker automatically inserts the `sh -c` wrapper for you.  That is, you can simplify this to

```bash
CMD envsubst '$PORT' < /etc/nginx/conf.d/configfile.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

with one fewer level of quoting.

**The `nginx` image already knows how to do this.**  As of Nginx 1.19, the [Docker Hub `nginx` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx) already knows how to run this `envsubst` command (search that page for "Using environment variables in nginx configuration"), and the base image already has a `CMD` that launches Nginx.  So if you put the templated configuration file in the correct location, you don't need this long-winded `CMD` at all.

Copying and tweaking the complete Dockerfile from the page you link to:

```bash
FROM node:14-alpine as react-build
...
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/templates/default.conf.template
# NOTE: different path    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

COPY --from=react-build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
ENV PORT 8080
ENV HOST 0.0.0.0
EXPOSE 8080
# No CMD in this derived Dockerfile
```

**This setup builds a static React application.**  It uses a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/) to first compile the application to static files, then copy those into the Nginx image.

```bash
FROM node:14-alpine as react-build
WORKDIR /app
...
RUN yarn build

FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=react-build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

If you need to use Nginx to proxy a server-side application, you need to run this in a separate container.  You ask about this in a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74420097/npm-not-found-when-using-npm-run-start-command-within-shell-script-from-a-docker).